# Variable in jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, syntax

Hopefully this is a quick easy one for you.

Here is my code:

```
var p7slide = 0;
$("#p7-forward").click (function () {
    p7animate = null;
    if (p7slide == 6)   {
        $("#p7-6").fadeOut("slow", function ()  {
            p7slide = 0;            
        });
    }
    else    {
        p7slide++;
        $("#p7-" + p7slide).fadeIn("slow");
        <!--$("#p7-" + "p7slide - 1").fadeOut("slow");-->
    };
});
```

The part i refer to is the commented out line in the else statement.

What i need this to do is to find p7slide and take 1 from this value. Then use that as the selector. E.g. If p7slide = 2 the selector would put together #p7-1. For some reason this statement isn't working.

Any ideas what Ive done wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Note that HTML comments are invalid in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've hard coded it as a string rather than an operation.

replace

```
$("#p7-" + "p7slide - 1").fadeOut("slow");
```

with

```
var slideNumber = p7slide - 1;
$("#p7-" + slideNumber).fadeOut("slow");
```

---

**Note:** In JS, if you use `+` operator with a string first, then a number, then you'll concatenate the number as a string to the end of the first string, see: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the " " tags as you cannot use numeric functions on a string

```
 $("#p7-" + p7slide - 1).fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: `"you cannot use numeric functions on a string"` isn't accurate. `+` isn't a function, it's an operator. You can use operator with string, but if the first operand is a string, it will concatenate then number as a string to the first, see: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html for more details.